# Is there a way to automatically update a value based on the date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns, `startdate` (datetime) and `has_started` (boolean).

The user can give in this date at any given time. Is there a way to automatically update `has_started` once `startdate` is less than today's date? A script or something? Thanks!

Comment: So you mean has_started should be true if startdate is today or earlier?

Comment: Why have the column anyway? You can check that on-the-fly

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store time dependent data like that, because what's not started one day may be started the following day. Create a view instead that returns the has_started, always up to date!

Comment: Yes has_started should be true if the startdate given is less than today'date.

Comment: Do the same as Gordon Linoff, listen to my view advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*,
           (startdate <= curdate() then 1 else 0 end) as has_started
    from table t;
```

If you query the view, the `has_started` column will be updated when *accessed*.  The value doesn't need to be stored in the database.

(Note:  if there is a time component, you can use `now()` instead of `curdate()`.)

Comment: If i understand correctly,  the view is only executed when a query is made to the table yes?  Is there a way to schedule a view?

Comment: @lot, the has_started value is "calculated" when you select from the view. The value is not stored anywhere.